# How to determine the location of files installed by a package on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, package-management

Is there a simple yum command or some other that indicates where abouts the files belonging to a particular package have been installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rpm -ql packagename
```

Comment: I think that does the reverse of what I want. It looks like you give it a file, and it tells you which package it belongs to.

Comment: Good grief, you're right.  Too quick off the keyboard.

Comment: All fixed now.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: yep, that does it :) I wonder why one might want to use the other way that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is another way of doing it too:

`$ rpm -q --filesbypkg packagename`